# Get System Time In MilliSeconds as an int/double

Tags: c++, qt, time

I am new to c++ but I just cant get this to work at all. I am trying to get the system current time in ms and do something with it but it wont work what I have tried.

Qt

```
 QDateTime qt = new QDateTime();
  int x = qt.currentDateTimeUtc();
    if(x%5 ==0){
        //something

     }
```

c++

```
     double sysTime = time(0);
if(sysTime%5.00 ==0.00){


}
```

I get invalid operands of type double to binary operator error. I have no idea why? Can anyone point in the right direction

Comment: a) You can´t do modulo with doubles, b) time() returns an int (and no ms)

Answer (score 2):

For QT, try using the function `QDateTime::toMSecsSinceEpoch()`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch

This will return a qint64 http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint64-typedef

Comment: how do I perform a % on this then, ill get error because of types

Comment: qint64 is a typedef for long long int (__int64 on Windows).  You cannot perform modulus on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to [get the unix timestamp in milliseconds in C](http://www.currentmillis.com/#c) you can try this code:

```
include "time.h"
...
time_t seconds;
time(&seconds);
unsigned long long millis = (unsigned long long)seconds * 1000;
```

Though please note this is multiplied by 1000 - it looks like milliseconds but the accuracy is that of seconds - which judging by your `x % 5` code might be enough if you're trying to do something every 5 seconds, so the following should be enough:

```
time_t seconds; time(&seconds);
```